# Unhandled Promise Rejection: integrating async function under condition

Tags: javascript, node.js

as in this program I've working on, I'm trying to put a async function under a condition: the condition checks correctly,but at a certain point I'm getting this error, and I don't know what to do. the code even works correctly, until the condition is satisfied.
I get to "console.log("CHECK PASSED PARAMS: ");"   and it errors out

```
bot.on("text", (ctx) => {
    
      let input = ctx.message.text;
      let inputArray = input.split("#");

      console.log("test is " + inputArray[1]);

          let message = "";
          inputArray.shift();  
          message = inputArray.join(" ");
              
          let messageArray =  message.split("/");

          let symbol = messageArray[0] + "/USDT";
          console.log(messageArray[0]);

          inputArraystring = String(inputArray);

          console.log( "TIPOARRAYSTRING: " + typeof(inputArraystring))
          //console.log( "inputarray data type : " + typeof(inputArray));
          
        
          ctx.reply(symbol);
          console.log(messageArray);

          


     waitUntil()
    .interval(500)
    .times(10)
    .condition(function(cb) {
      
      process.nextTick(function() {

        cb (inputArraystring == "BTC" ? true : false);
        
      });

    })

    .done(function(check) {


      if (check == true){

        console.log("GETTING HERE");

        myFetch(ctx,symbol);


        async function myFetch(ctx,symbol) {

          console.log("CHECK PASSED PARAMS: ");

          console.log(symbol);

    
          //--------------RSI--------------------
    

          let rsifast = (await alerts.rsiCheck(14, 76, 28, 'binance', symbol, '15m', false));
          let rsislow = (await alerts.rsiCheck(14, 76, 28, 'binance', symbol, '1h', false));
```

Comment: Apparently `alerts.rsiCheck` throws an error that you're not handling anywhere. The unhandled rejection message should tell you what the error is.

Comment: this is the error "node:internal/process/promises:245
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "Ticker is not supported".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'"

Comment: There you got it: "*Ticker is not supported*". Whatever that means.

Comment: thx, I fixed in the end